# Make buttons slide up in accordion in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, accordion, slide

I have in React an accordion with buttons that slide up/down content, like on this [image](https://yuntu-tek.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/accordion_jquery.gif)

I made some functional components and things look like this:

```
<SlideButtonContainer>
    <SlideButton title="Title goes here">
        Content goes here
    </SlideButton>
    <SlideButton title="Title goes here">
        Content goes here
    </SlideButton>
</SlideButtonContainer>
```

Clicking a `SlideButton` calls a function `handleClick` that changes the state `opened` of the component, making it slide its content up on `false` or down on `true`.

But how could I make all the other `SlideButtons` inside `SlideButtonContainer` set their state `opened` to `false`?

`SlideButton` uses [SlideDown from this repo](https://github.com/frankwallis/react-slidedown) and is as follows:

```
export default function SlideButton(props) {
    const [opened, setOpened] = useState(false);

    function handleClick() {
        setOpened(!opened);
    }

    return (
        <div className="slideButton">
            <div className="slideButtonButton" onClick={handleClick}>
                <div>
                    {props.title}
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="slideButtonContents">
                <SlideDown>
                    {opened ? props.children : null}
                </SlideDown>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

`SlideButtonContainer` is just a styled div

```
export default function SlideButtonContainer(props) {
    return (
        <div className="slideButtonContainer">
            { props.children }
        </div>  
    );
}
```

Comment: Can you update your question to include the implementation details of all these components in a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible Code Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Move state to parent: https://codesandbox.io/s/billowing-resonance-dri8d?file=/src/Accordion.js

Comment: @Branislav But that would require to make a component for each group of SlideButtons. I don't want to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved.
In `SlideButtonContainer` I use `React.cloneElement` on `render` and set refs to its children, and I can use children's function with this loop:

```
for (var ref in this.refs) {
    this.refs[ref].slideUp();
}
```